# How to print only the duplicate values from a text file?

Tags: shell, text-processing

Suppose there is a column of numeric values like following:

File1:

```
1 
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
5
6
```

I want the output:

```
3  
4
```

That is, only the repeated lines. Are there any command line tools to find this out in Linux? (NB: The values are numerically sorted).

Comment: See `man uniq`.

Comment: Related, more difficult question: [Delete duplicate lines pairwise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/277365/135943)

Answer (score 190, accepted):

You can use `uniq(1)` for this if the file is sorted:

```
uniq -d file.txt
```

If the file is not sorted, run it through `sort(1)` first:

```
sort file.txt | uniq -d
```

This will print out the duplicates only.

Technically the input does not need to be in sorted order, but the duplicates in the file need to be consecutive. The usual way to achieve that is to sort the file.

Comment: what if I want the triplicates only to be printed?

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK `sort | uniq -c | grep '^\s*3\s' | sed 's/^\s*[0-9]*\s*//'` for triplicates; replace "3" with any N for N-plicates

Comment: @MiNdFrEaK `sort | uniq -c | sed -n 's/^[[:blank:]]*3[[:blank:]]\{1,\}//p'` for triplicates

Comment: @camh can you do this on csv files as well? only values of a certain column?

Comment: sort file.txt | uniq -d

Comment: This only works for numbers, not for characters, see my answer for a number and character solution: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/548813

Comment: @jasonleonhard uniq will work for any text, not just numbers. All your answer adds to the command is `sort`, which I mention in my answer: "The input file needs to be sorted ... so run it through sort first if it is not".

Comment: This is incorrect if file.txt is not sorted. You should type `sort file.txt | uniq -d` to first `sort` and then find the non-uniq (`uniq -d`) lines.

Comment: @amc I do say in the last sentence that it needs to be sorted. Should I reword that perhaps?

Comment: @camh I think that is best! Maybe the simplest thing is to modify the first sentence: "You can use `uniq(1)` only if file.txt is sorted". If you want to be really clear perhaps write the case when the file isn't sorted (as I wrote before).

Answer (score 9):

### `uniq` requires your list to be ordered, sort defaults to alphabetical

`sort path/to/your/filename | uniq -d`

or

`cat fileName | sort | uniq -d`

Comment: Technically uniq doesn't specifically require them to be sorted, just that the duplicates are ordered consecutively - which sorting guarantees, but in my case was not needed, and I'm only mentioning it because it prevented me from having to buffer the entire input stream to sort it, because I could already guarantee the duplicates were consecutive.

Answer (score 3):

Execute this: `perl -ne 'print if $a{$_}++' filename.txt`

Comment: It gives `3\n3\n4\n\4n` for the input File1 which is obviously wrong.

Comment: the perl snip i find myself revisiting provides the number of incidences of each line so it can be piped, sorted, and filtered as needed:   perl -ne '$a{$_}++; END { while(($k,$v)=each %a){printf "%d\t%s", $v,$k}}' filename

Comment: Is there a way to do that on a specific column separated by a given field separator?

Comment: As indicated by yaegashi, a small fix is needed to fulfill the requirements: perl -ne 'print if 1==$a{$_}++' filename.txt   Among all the answer, it is my favorite, because the other answers require to preprocess all the data with a full sort. This answer starts output results more quickly and efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Using `uniq` and `awk`:

```
cat File1  | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1 { print $2 }'
```

Comment: This work, but I don't see why you pipe the output of `cat`?

Comment: not everyone knows you can do `uniq -c File1` and similarly with many other tools. That is probably what is going on here.

Comment: Could still redirect `uniq -c < File1`. In particular, necessary with `tr`, as it does not process file args.